# WPF , howto to know that a task has completed

Tags: wpf, events, asynchronous, task, taskcompletionsource

I am developping a MVVM WPF app, and I have some task to do.

1. first load files csv and parse it
2. In background don´t block the ui Thread and save the values in the database.To save the rows to the database I need to be with Async Await Task.

My problem is I don´t know how to notice the user with a popup notification or something else that values are already saved in database.

in My ViewModel

```
private void SaveDatasInDatabase()
{
            ShowLoadingPanel = true;
            _service.SaveValuesInDatabase(rows);
}


 private async void startActions()
{
     await LoadandParseCsv();
     await SaveDatasInDatabase();
}
```

in my Service.cs

```
public string SaveDatasInDatabase(List<Object> rows)
{
   Task.Run(async () =>
    {
            await SaveEntity(rows);
            return "Done";
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Jolynce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the task has completed once the remainder of the `startActions()` method is executed:

```
private async void startActions()
{
    await LoadandParseCsv();
    await SaveDatasInDatabase();

    MessageBox.Show("done");
}
```

...provided that actually await the `SaveEntity` method in the `SaveDatasInDatabase()` method:

```
public async Task<string> SaveDatasInDatabase(List<Object> rows)
{
    await SaveEntity(rows);
    return "Done";
}
```

If you just call `Task.Run` without awaiting the returned `Task`, you don't know when it has finished.

The return type of the `SaveDatasInDatabase` method should be `Task` or `Task<T>` for you to be able to await it. The same thing applies to the `SaveEntity` method.

Comment: Thanks mm8. I will try your solution.